# How can I compare two arrays and display differences for each key (multidimensional arrays)?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays I want to compare:

animals1:

```
array(4) {
  ["1234"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(19) "cat"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "fred"
    ["food"]=>
    string(32) "milk"
  }
  ["5678"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(19) "dog"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "sam"
    ["food"]=>
    string(32) "chicken"
  }
  ["shop"]=>
  string(12) "petcenter"
}
```

animals2:

```
array(4) {
  ["1234"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(19) "cat"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "tom"
    ["food"]=>
    string(32) "juice"
  }
  ["5678"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(19) "dog"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "sam"
    ["food"]=>
    string(32) "fish"
  }
  ["shop"]=>
  string(12) "petcenter"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($animals1 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (array_diff($animals2[$k1], $animals1[$k1])){
      $diff[$k1] = array_diff($animals2[$k1], $animals1[$k1]);
   }
} 
foreach ($animals2 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (array_diff($animals1[$k1], $animals2[$k1])){
      $diff2[$k1] = array_diff($animals1[$k1], $animals2[$k1]);
   }
}
function result1($item, $key){
   echo $key."1 = ".$item;
   echo "<br>";
}
function result2($item, $key){
   echo $key."2 = ".$item;
   echo "<br>";
}
foreach ($diff as $d => $key){

    foreach ($animals1 as $p => $row) {
            if ($p == $d){
                  echo "Error for animal".$row["animal"];
                  echo "with the name:".$row["name"].".";
            }   
        }   
}
array_walk_recursive($diff, 'result1');
array_walk_recursive($diff2, 'result2');
```

My result is:

```
Error for animal cat with name fred.
Error for animal dog with name sam.

name1 = fred
food1 = milk
food1 = chicken

name2 = tom
food2 = juice
food2 = fish
```

But what I would need is this:

```
Error for animal cat with name fred.

name1 = fred
name2 = tom

food1 = milk
food2 = juice

Error for animal dog with name sam.

food1 = chicken
food2 = fish
```

That means, at first I want to display that there is an error for a specific animal with a specific name. After this, I want to display the differences. that means always the value of `animal1` and after that the value of `animal2`.
I do not know how to change my code the best way to achieve the result I wish.

---

This is the output of Standej:

```
Error for animal cat with name fred.

name1 = fred
food1 = milk
food1 = chicken

name2 = tom
food2 = juice
food2 = fish

Error for animal dog with name sam.

name1 = fred
food1 = milk
food1 = chicken

name2 = tom
food2 = juice
food2 = fish
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php two Multidimensional Array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856743/php-two-multidimensional-array-difference)

Comment: @Elias Nicolas I need to compare the keys differently

Comment: Using `array_diff` for this will lead to strange results if the `name` value of one cat equals the `food` value of the other cat, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reorder your code if you want reordered results

```
foreach ($animals1 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (array_diff($animals2[$k1], $animals1[$k1])){
      $diff[$k1] = array_diff($animals2[$k1], $animals1[$k1]);
   }
} 
foreach ($animals2 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (array_diff($animals1[$k1], $animals2[$k1])){
      $diff2[$k1] = array_diff($animals1[$k1], $animals2[$k1]);
   }
}
function result1($item, $key){
   echo $key."1 = ".$item;
   echo "<br>";
}
function result2($item, $key){
   echo $key."2 = ".$item;
   echo "<br>";
}
foreach ($diff as $d => $key){

    foreach ($animals1 as $p => $row) {
            if ($p == $d){
                  echo "Error for animal".$row["animal"];
                  echo "with the name:".$row["name"].".";
// Put your functions inside loop where you printing errors
                  array_walk_recursive($diff, 'result1');
                  array_walk_recursive($diff2, 'result2');
// End of change
            }   
        }   
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Thank you, but I do not get the output I needed. I posted the result of your answer in my question.

Comment: I have a question. You must use array_walk_recursive or I can try to write you results on different way without use of this function? @Jarla

Comment: I am happy for every way to the result :) Doesn't need to be array_walk_recursive

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `array_diff` is that it only compares values, not the keys, so you could have a failure to detect a difference if the name of one cat is equal to the food of the other, and vice versa.

It would be an improvement to use `array_diff_assoc` which also compares the keys.

Still, the code would miss some differences, like when the first animal has a missing key, e.g. no `food`. The `$diff` array will not have this difference, and since the code iterates over `$diff`, the corresponding animal will not be included in the output if all the rest is equal.

The original code also assumes that `animal` and `name` keys are always there.

Here is some code that should work even if some keys are missing on either side:

```
function outputDiff($animals1, $animals2) {
    foreach($animals1 as $key => $animal1) {
        // skip animals that only exist in one of the two arrays
        if (!is_array($animal1) || !isset($animals2[$key])) continue;
        $animal2 = $animals2[$key];
        if (!is_array($animal2)) continue;
        // add "animal" and "name" keys to first animal when they are missing
        $animal1 = array_merge(array("animal"=>"(unknown)","name"=>"(unknown)"),
                     $animal1);
        // collect the keys that either animal has:
        $properties = array_unique(array_merge(
                        array_keys($animal1), array_keys($animal2)));
        $equal = true;
        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            // get values from both sides, default to '(unknown)'
            $value1 = isset($animal1[$property]) ? $animal1[$property] : '(unknown)';
            $value2 = isset($animal2[$property]) ? $animal2[$property] : '(unknown)';
            if ($value1 !== $value2) {
                if ($equal) { 
                    // display header
                    echo "<h4>Error for animal {$animal1['animal']}" .
                              "with name {$animal1['name']}</h4>";
                    $equal = false;
                }
                // display detail
                echo "<p>{$property}1 = $value1<br>"; 
                echo "{$property}2 = $value2</p>";
            }
        }   
    }
}

// Set-up test data
$animals1 = array(
  "1234"=>array(
    "animal"=>"cat",
     "name"=>"fred",
    "food"=>"milk"
  ),
  "5678"=>array(
    "animal"=>"dog",
    "name"=>"sam",
    "food"=>"chicken"
  ),
  "8888"=>array(
    "animal"=>"cow",
    "name"=>"freddy",
    "food"=>"grass"
  ),
  "shop"=>"petcenter"
);
$animals2 = array(
  "1234"=>array(
    "animal"=>"cat",
    "name"=>"tom",
    "food"=>"juice"
  ),
  "5678"=>array(
    "animal"=>"dog",
    "name"=>"sam",
    "food"=>"fish"
  ),
  "shop"=>"petcenter"
);

// Perform test
outputDiff($animals1, $animals2);
```

This code outputs `html` tags (remove them if they bother you). The output of the above is:

> **Error for animal cat with name fred**
>
> name1 = fred
>
> name2 = tom
>
> food1 = milk
>
> food2 = juice
>
> **Error for animal dog with name sam**
>
> food1 = chicken
>
> food2 = fish